if $\forall{g}\in\mathcal{C^2([0,1])} \ \int_{0}^{1} fg = 0$ imply $f=0$
here is the following statement:
Take $f\in \mathcal{C}^0([0,1])$ such that $\forall{g}\in\mathcal{C^2([0,1])}$:
$$\int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(t) = 0$$
Show $f$ is identically zero.
My question is whether this argument im going to present is too straightforward and if i'm not missing something:
Attempt:
Suppose by contradiction there are points such that $f$ is not identically zero. Let's take one of these points we shall denote $a$ (suppose for now it's not an endpoint but the proof doesn't change at all) and notice the following - by continuity of $f$, (WLOG we assume $f(a)>0$) there is a neighborhood of $f$ we will call $\mathcal{I}=[a-\delta, a+\delta]$ s.t $f>0$. Yet we can thus choose a function $g\in\mathcal{C}^2([0,1])$ which is positive over that interval (case $f>0$, otherwise make $g<0$ over that neighborhood). BWOC, we have proven the statement. Thanks in advance for any feedback!

You are right, it is that easy. This also holds if $f \in L^1_{loc}([0, 1])$ however, which is a bit more nontrivial.

thanks a lot, and just as a self note, the function g we should pick is of polynomial nature (we could construct such a polynomial using lagrange interpolation - this should work since the number of change of signs must be finite by continuity of f, and if that isn't the case, the function would be identically zero leading to a contradiction).

I'd say even easier. By writing the polynomial in its factorized form, you can control where its zeros are. Everywhere else, it has a distinct sign
